# Ant Junit & Selenium no information in reports

Tags: eclipse, selenium, ant, junit, webdriver

I am running so juit tests in eclipse usin Ant and Selenium Webdriver.
The tests run as expected and I see the result in the console and the eb report is generated but the results are not included.
Below is my build.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="F:/Program Files (x86)/eclipse/"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.7"/>
<property name="source" value="1.7"/>
<property name="junit.output.dir" value="C:/Users/kev/workspace_hlgliveTest/hlglive/junit/"/>
<path id="hlglive.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="C:/Selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="hlglive.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>
<target name="classHlglive">
    <java classname="hlglive.classHlglive" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="hlglive.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="hmliveCH">
    <java classname="hlglive.hmliveCH" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="hlglive.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="junitreport">
    <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <include name="*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>    
</project>
```

And here is the console output

---

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\kev\workspace_hlgliveTest\hlglive\build.xml
build-subprojects:
init:
build-project:
 [echo] hlglive: C:\Users\kev\workspace_hlgliveTest\hlglive\build.xml
build:
hmliveCH:
 [java] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d5321e)) on port 24805
 [java] Only local connections are allowed.
 [java] Starting Chrome login Test
 [java] Current page title is: Haulage Manager Live
 [java] Testing combination of user name:  and password: 
 [java] Current page title is: Haulage Manager Live
 [java] Testing combination of user name: KEV and password: 
 [java] Current page title is: Haulage Manager Live
 [java] Testing combination of user name: KEV and password: bollo
 [java] Current page title is: Haulage Manager Live
 [java] Testing combination of user name: KEVIN and password: bollox
 [java] Current page title is: Haulage Manager Live
 [java] Testing combination of user name: KEV and password: bollox
 [java] Current page title is: Haulage Manager Live
 [java] Current page title is: Haulage Manager Live
 [java] Chrome Test complete
junitreport:
[junitreport] Processing C:\Users\kev\workspace_hlgliveTest\hlglive\junit\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\kev\AppData\Local\Temp\null978404570
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/F:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 565ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Users\kev\AppData\Local\Temp\null978404570
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 18 seconds
```

---

So all seems to run ok but when I look at the generated html pages all I see is this.

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone point me to where I am going wrong please.

Thanks

Kev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<junitreport> combines the results of tests run using the <junit> task. You used  to run a standalone program rather than using <junit> to run a test suite. Therefore, <junitreport> didn't see any  tests run and correctly reported that zero tests were run.